# Need assistance in creating a function with means and standard deviations

Tags: r, function, formula

I have a dataset like this - basically I have two groups of patients:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), age = c(45, 67, 
43, 23, 78, 87, 12)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

[image]

This is what I wrote:

```
formula <- function(x,y,z,t){
  (x - y) / sqrt((z^2 + t^2)/2)
  
}
```

Right now, I have to manually write all the four elements of the function e.g. `formula(x,y,z,t)`

However, I would like to transform this function in this way:

```
x <- mean age of group 1
y <- mean age of group 2
z <- standard deviation (of age) in group 1
t <- standard deviation (of age) in group 2
```

So that I can simply write something like `formula(df$age, df$group)` and it automatically calculates mean and standard deviation in the correct group and uses the formula.

I am new to writing functions so please help

Comment: The formula of the image seems to be for a variable with bernouli distribution, and age isn't one. Are you sure about the logic behind this calculation? You should explain how the symbols in the image relate to the variables in your df

Comment: @Ricardo I pasted the wrong image. The correct formula is the one in the code I wrote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the values of `x` that belong to the first group with `x[group == 1]`, and do the same for group 2. Then just use your formula:

```
formula <- function(x, group){
  treat <- x[group == 1]
  control <- x[group == 2]
  
  (mean(treat) - mean(control)) / sqrt((var(treat) + var(control))/2)
}

formula(df$age, df$group)
[1] 0.05857275
```

Comment: Thank you. Let's suppose that "group" changes, e.g. in one dataset it is called "category". Is there a way that the function automatically reads df$category so I don't have to replace all "group" with "category"?

Comment: Ideally instead of "group" maybe we can write y, and y is the part of "df$group" after the dollar symbol so that the "y" assumes the value specified e.g formula(df$age,df$category). I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I just replaced "Y" instead of group and it works. Thank you!